# Smoothly change a JavaFX effect

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

Is it possible to smoothly change an effect in JavaFX?
I've tried a lot of options, but nothing works.

For example - Java:

```
void effectChange(Node node) {
    // Node Effect = ColorAdjust (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(node.effectProperty(), new ColorAdjust(-0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2.0), keyValue);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(keyFrame);
    timeline.play();
}
```

For example - Kotlin:

```
fun effectChange(node: Node) {
    // Node Effect = ColorAdjust (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    val keyValue = KeyValue(node.effectProperty(), ColorAdjust(-0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    val keyFrame = KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2.0), keyValue)
    val timeline = Timeline(keyFrame)
    timeline.play()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are timelining wrong property. Instead of changing the effect you should change effect's property. Take a look at the next example:

```
    Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");
    ColorAdjust effect = new ColorAdjust(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    btn.setEffect(effect);
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(effect.hueProperty(), -0.8);
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2.0), keyValue);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(keyFrame);
        timeline.play();
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks, now everything works
Could you also say how to make it repetitive from the beginning?
//Start -1.0
//End 1.0
//..0.9, 1.0, -1.0, -0.9..

Comment: @Nourepide `timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);` you may also want `timeline.setAutoReverse(true);`